# SAS how to get random selection by group randomly split into multiple groups

Tags: sql, sas, sample, proc

I have a simple data set of customers (about 40,000k)
It looks like:

```
customerid, group, other_variable
a,blue,y
b,blue,x
c,blue,z
d,green,y
e,green,d
f,green,r
g,green,e
```

I want to randomly select for each group, Y amounts of customers (along with their other variable(s).
The catch is, i want to have two random selections of Y amounts for each group
i.e.

```
4000 random green customers split into two sets of 2000 randomly
and 4000 random blue customers split into two sets of 2000 randomly
```

This is because I have different messages to give to the two different splits
I'm not sampling with replacement. Needs to be unique customers

Would prefer a solution in PROC SQL but happy for alternative solution in sas if proc sql isn't idea

Comment: Perhaps this document (pdf) would help: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/168-31.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`proc surveyselect` is the general tool of choice for random sampling in SAS.  The code is very simple, I would just sample 4000 of each group, then assign a new subgroup every 2000 rows, since the data is in a random order anyway (although sorted by group).

The default sampling method for `proc surveyselect` is `srs`, which is simple random sampling without replacement, exactly what is required here.

Here's some example code.

```
/* create dummy dataset */
data have;
do customerid = 1 to 10000;
length group other_variable $8;
if rand('uniform')<0.5 then group = 'blue'; /* assign blue or green with equal likelihood */
    else group = 'green';
other_variable = byte(97+(floor((1+122-97)*rand('uniform')))); /* random letter between a and z */
output;
end;
run;

/* dataset must be sorted by group variable */
proc sort data=have;
by group;
run;

/* extract random sample of 4000 from each group */
proc surveyselect data=have
                    out=want
                    n=4000
                    seed=12345; /* specify seed to enable results to be reproduced */
strata group; /* set grouping variable */
run;

/* assign a new subgroup for every 2000 rows */
data want;
set want;
sub=int((_n_-1)/2000)+1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data custgroup ;
do i=1 to nobs;
set sorted_data nobs=nobs ;
point = ranuni(0);
end;

proc sort data = custgroup out=sortedcust
by group point;
run;

data final;
set sortedcust;
by group point;
if first group then i=1;
i+1;
run;
```

Basically what I am doing is first assign a random number to all observations in the data set. Then perform sorting based on the variable `group` and `point`.

Now I achieved a random sequence of observation within group. `i=1` and `i+1`
would be to identify the row of observation(s) within group. This means would avoid extracting duplicated observations .  Use `output` statement as well to control where you want to store the observation based on `i.`

My approach may not be the most efficient one.

Comment: `ranuni(0)` should not be used in a case like this.  Always, always, always seed with a positive integer, so the sample can be replicated if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should do it. First, you will need to generate a random number. As Joe said above, it is better to seed it with a specific number so that you can reproduce the sample if necessary. Then you can use Proc Sql with the outobs statement to generate a sample.

(BTW, it would be a good idea not to name a variable 'group'.)

```
data YourDataSet;
set YourDataSet;
myrandomnumber = ranuni(123);
run;

proc sql outobs=2000;
create table bluesample as
select *
from YourDataSet
where group eq 'blue'
order by myrandomnumber;
quit;

proc sql outobs=2000;
create table greensample as
select *
from YourDataSet
where group eq 'green'
order by myrandomnumber;
quit;
```